# Cannot open/decrypt/encrypt .docx with password longer than 15 characters in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, ms-word, office-interop

### Problem

The following code works for .docx files with password upto 15 characters:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var app = new Word.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open("file.docx", PasswordDocument: "<short password>");
```

For longer password the .Open method fails with *COMExcetion* of message: "Command failed".

### Question(s)

With longer password, how can I:

1. **Encrypt**/**decrypt** word files?
2. **Recognize** that given **password opens the file**?
3. (optionally) **Open the file in** Microsoft **Word** application **programmatically**?

Along with the links also sample code would be greatly appreciated.

### Notes

- Tried in all versions of *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll*: 12.0.0.0, 14.0.0.0 and 15.0.0.0
- [Spire.Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html) seems to be solving points 1. and 2., but it is commercial and free version is [pretty limited](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html).

Comment: Did you try to do the same operation manually? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works. At least in Word 2010 and 2013 you can save file with password longer than 15 characters.