# Word2013 not open password file having length > 15 in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var app = new Word.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open("file.docx", PasswordDocument: "<password>");
```

I am trying to open word file having password length > 15.
It gives error of invalid command line.

**Error Detail:**
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Application.exe
Additional information: Command failed

Note: I need resolution for word interop i may not allow to user third party.
Same file can open by giving manual password.

Any one have any resolution?

Comment: Add detail error which you are getting

Comment: An [unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820525/cannot-open-decrypt-encrypt-docx-with-password-longer-than-15-characters-in-ne) encounter the exact same problem, the asker used paid third party lib successfully

Comment: i edited my post for added comment

Comment: Just to ensure that there is no other error, try to open it with app.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog . If it works, only that method may be bad, if not, there can be another problem.

Comment: Dexion seems like there is another problem